# How to pass NSMutableArray data from a UIViewController to a TableView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to populate a subview table with data created by modifying an `NSMutableArray`. Basically, a person answers 10 questions and I want to show a subview with the correct answer image and label also a checkmark image to determine if the user got the question right or wrong. I have created a custom cell inside the tableview and linked them to a table cell view controller (resultCellView).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface resultsViewCell : UITableViewCell


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultsFlag;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultsIcon;


@end
```

The subview is part of the this View Controller `GamePlayViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "resultsViewCell.h"

@interface GamePlayViewController : UIViewController {

NSMutableArray *questionsArray;
NSMutableArray *answersArray;
NSInteger gameSelected;
NSMutableArray *revealArray;
NSTimer *questionTimer;
BOOL GameInProgress; 

int random;
int questionTimerCounter;
int loopCounter;
int runningScore;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *resultsTable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *resultsView;

@end
```

The game loop runs on this View Controller `GamePlayViewController.m` File and then calls the function animate results:

```
- (void)gameLoop {

if (loopCounter < 10){
    revealArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",   @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", nil];
    cover1.alpha = 1.0;
    cover2.alpha = 1.0;
    cover3.alpha = 1.0;
    cover4.alpha = 1.0;
    cover5.alpha = 1.0;
    cover6.alpha = 1.0;
    cover7.alpha = 1.0;
    cover8.alpha = 1.0;
    coreView.alpha = 1.0;

NSDictionary *question = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

question = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter];

questionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[question objectForKey:@"imageNames"]];
[self getAnswers];
}
else {
    //NSLog(@"finished");
    [self animateResults];
}

}
```

the animate results function populates the final score but I am unsure how to proceed populating table.

```
-(void) animateResults {

_resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Scored %d", runningScore   ];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    _resultsView.frame = self.view.frame;


} completion:^(BOOL finished){


   NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);

}];


}
```

I NSLog the questionsArray created by this method:

```
- (void) answerMethod:(int)answerBtn {
if (answerBtn == random) {
    //NSLog(@"correct!");
    int maxScore = 10000;
    int userScore = maxScore - (questionTimerCounter*1000);
    NSLog(@"%d", userScore);
    runningScore = runningScore + userScore;
    NSLog(@"%d" , runningScore);

    NSMutableDictionary *question = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    question = [[questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter]mutableCopy];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"correct"];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:userScore] forKey:@"score"];
    [questionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCounter withObject:question];


}
else {
   // NSLog(@"incorrect");

    NSMutableDictionary *question = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    question = [[questionsArray objectAtIndex:loopCounter]mutableCopy];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"correct"];
    [question setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"score"];
    [questionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:loopCounter withObject:question];
}


GameInProgress = NO;

loopCounter++;
[self revealAnswer];

}
```

The modified questionsArray is created but like I said I am unsure how to proceed from this point. I've tried adding this code to `GamePlayViewController.m` file:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//Return number of sections
    return 1;

}

//get number of rows by counting number of challenges
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
    return questionsArray.count;
}

//setup cells in tableView
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//setup cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"resultsListCell";
resultsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *results = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *resultsName = [results objectForKey:@"answers"];

BOOL correct = [[results objectForKey:@"correct"] boolValue];

if (!correct) {
    cell.resultsIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackIconLock.png"];
}

else{
    cell.resultsIcon.image = nil;
}

cell.resultsName.text = resultsName;

return cell;
}
```

But this code reveals nothing. I am still learning I've managed to get to this point. I've been able to get the ten questions to run properly but now I'm trying to get this final part done and to be honest I'm stuck on stupid. Just Have not been able to get it figured out. any HELP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should call [resultsTable reloadData] after updating your questionsArray.

Answer (score 0):

Where you modifying your `NSMutableArray`, call `[tableView reloadData]` after successfully modification. Hope this will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need set the delegate and data source of your table view to your view controller, then if the data is ready, call reloadData method of table view.

try to view the doc to learn more:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: I Tried to add the delegate and data source of my table view by control dragging to the GamePlayViewController. and added the [resultsTable reloadData] to the end of my answerMethod. But received a failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<GamePlayViewController: 0x7fbec0def530> error. Once the game tries to load the subview seems to be trying to load the table before the array is created. Thank you for answering and the reference material. I'll throughly give it read before proceeding.

Comment: you need register your cell class `- (void)registerClass:(nullable Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier `,otherwise, `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"resultsListCell";
resultsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`will get nil.

Comment: Thank you for all your help thus far, I am attempting to load this UIView _resultsView with the final score and the players question results.  I tried your suggestions but still to no avail. I Tried to add the delegate and data source of my table view by control dragging to the GamePlayViewController. and added the [resultsTable reloadData] to the end of my answerMethod. But received a failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<GamePlayViewController: 0x7fbec0def530> error. and also attempted to register my class still crashes on loading the GamePlayViewController. I know its user error.